Is the Planck mass the "lower limit" for gravity?
The Planck units are often treated as being the "lower limits" to things: the Planck length for length, the Planck time for time, etc.
But the Planck mass, which is about $2.2\times10^{-5}$ grams or $1.234\times10^{22}$ MeV/c$^2$, appears to be well above any known subatomic particle mass or the mass of atoms, and so not be a lower limit to "mass" itself, but then what is it a lower limit to?
Is it the minimal mass needed for gravity to have a non-zero effect (i.e. the mass needed for even the smallest amount of spacetime curvature to occur)?
While this would explain why we do not observe the effects of gravity on small scales, I must admit that I myself have some doubts on this idea. There is also the situation with the Planck charge, which is about twelve times more than a single electron charge. So, I am quite puzzled as to what the Planck mass could be a lower limit to then, aside from gravity.

$m_p$ is not a lower limit for gravity. It's just the value you get by algebraically manipulating $\hbar$, $G$ and $c$ until you get mass units.
If you need some numerical high explosives to blow up your intuition that Planck somehow must mean "minimum", try the Planck density (the density unit you get by such algebraic manipulation): $\rho_P = \dfrac{c^5}{\hbar G^2} = 5.1550×10^{96} kg/m^3$
Which is about $10^{79}$ times the density of an atomic nucleus.
As for gravity on small scales, my answer here may be useful: Does gravitation really exist at the particle level?_
